# Numerical solution of two equations in two functions

Tags: equation-solving

I would like to obtain a solution to the following two equations, where g0[y] and g1[y] are the unknown functions:

```
-0.23094021403064358` + (-2 g0[y] + g1[y])/(1.043747093724331` g0[y] + 1.0437470937243307` g1[y])
                      - (1.043747093724331` (-g0[y]^2 + g0[y] g1[y]))/(1.043747093724331` g0[y] + 1.0437470937243307` g1[y])^2
                      - 0.9580865000847749` Log[E^(1/2 (1 + y)^2) Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] g0[y]] == 0

-0.23094021403064324` + (-g0[y] + 2 g1[y])/(1.043747093724331` g0[y] + 1.0437470937243307` g1[y])
                      - (1.0437470937243307` (-g0[y] g1[y] + g1[y]^2))/(1.043747093724331` g0[y] + 1.0437470937243307` g1[y])^2
                      - 0.9580865000847752` Log[E^(1/2 (-1 + y)^2) Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] g1[y]] == 0
```

I dont need an analytical solution, a numerical solution would suffice. I tried using `Solve` but I didn't manage to obtain any solutions.

Comment: Consider using FindRoot.  After obtaining roots for a particular value of y, use those roots as initial guesses for a nearby value of y, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to elaborate the advice of  bbgodfrey. I take it, you do not need to have that precise numbers. The 2-digit precision is enough? Then here are your equations:

```
  eq1 = -0.23094021403064358` + (-2 g0[y] + 
      g1[y])/(1.043747093724331` g0[y] + 
      1.0437470937243307` g1[y]) - (1.043747093724331` (-g0[y]^2 + 
        g0[y] g1[y]))/(1.043747093724331` g0[y] + 
       1.0437470937243307` g1[y])^2 - 
   0.9580865000847749` Log[E^(1/2 (1 + y)^2) Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] g0[y]] == 0

eq2 = -0.23094021403064324` + (-g0[y] + 
      2 g1[y])/(1.043747093724331` g0[y] + 
      1.0437470937243307` g1[
        y]) - (1.0437470937243307` (-g0[y] g1[y] + 
        g1[y]^2))/(1.043747093724331` g0[y] + 
       1.0437470937243307` g1[y])^2 - 
   0.9580865000847752` Log[E^(1/2 (-1 + y)^2) Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] g1[y]] ==0
```

This will make them less ugly and rationalize them. The latter will help Mma to work faster:

```
 rnd[expr_, n_Integer] := expr /. x_Real :> Round[x, .1/10^(n - 1)];
eq1A = Rationalize[Map[rnd[#, 2] &, eq1, Infinity] /. f_[y] -> f]

(*   -(23/100) + (-2 g0 + g1)/((26 g0)/25 + (26 g1)/25) - (
  26 (-g0^2 + g0 g1))/(25 ((26 g0)/25 + (26 g1)/25)^2) - 
  24/25 Log[E^(1/2 (1 + y)^2) g0 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]] == 0    *)
```

and

```
 eq2A = eq1A = 
  Rationalize[Map[rnd[#, 2] &, eq2, Infinity] /. f_[y] -> f]

(* -(23/100) + (-g0 + 2 g1)/((26 g0)/25 + (26 g1)/25) - (
  26 (-g0 g1 + g1^2))/(25 ((26 g0)/25 + (26 g1)/25)^2) - 
  24/25 Log[E^(1/2 (-1 + y)^2) g1 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]] == 0     *)
```

These equations can be solved with the FindRoot for a sequence of `y`values and the solution is formed as a list with the structure {y,{g0,g1}}:

```
  lst = Table[{y, (FindRoot[{-(23/100) + (-2 g0 + g1)/((26 g0)/25 + (
           26 g1)/25) - (26 (-g0^2 + g0 g1))/(
          25 ((26 g0)/25 + (26 g1)/25)^2) - 
          24/25 Log[E^(1/2 (1 + y)^2) g0 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]] == 
         0, -(23/100) + (-g0 + 2 g1)/((26 g0)/25 + (26 g1)/25) - (
          26 (-g0 g1 + g1^2))/(25 ((26 g0)/25 + (26 g1)/25)^2) - 
          24/25 Log[E^(1/2 (-1 + y)^2) g1 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]] == 0}, {{g0, 
         1}, {g1, 2}}] /. {x_ -> a_, xx_ -> b_} -> {a, b}) // 
    Chop}, {y, 0, 2, 0.1}]
```

Evaluate it and you will get the list in question. 
Now you may do whatever you need with this list. For example, one may plot it:

```
 ListPlot[{(lst /. {x_, {y_, z_}} -> {x, 
      y}), (lst /. {x_, {y_, z_}} -> {x, z})}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["y", 16, Italic], 
   Row[{Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(g\), \(0\)]\)", 16, Italic, Blue],
      Style["  \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(g\), \(1\)]\)", 16, Italic, 
      Red]}]}]
```

This should look like the following:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: What is the range of the plot? Is it possible to get a figure for y in -6 to 6?

Comment: @Seyhmus Güngören The PlotRange is up to you. I did not fix it, but you can do it as you like. You should understand that I do not know, what are you after with this problem, so I just indicate the direction in which you could come. Concerning going in `y `from -6 to 6 just try, and have a look at the lst output. I remember that at y>2 the result became complex, That is, no real solution. However, I have arbitrarily chosen the initial guess: `g0=1; g1=2 `. It may be that with some other initial values you will obtain solutions. I recommend to ParametricPlot3D first your functions.